# Oracle report about executed queries for a specific user before TDE activation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I need to run a performance comparison before activating Oracle TDE on our database (12c).

My idea was to monitor executed queries for a specific user (Java EE App Server) and then replay these queries on a cloned Oracle TDE instance to compare response times.

We found the Oracle AWR feature, however, in this report over 90% of the queries are "system" queries which were not triggered by the App Server's JDBC driver(, but by internal oracle jobs/optimizations?).

Is there some functionality to restrict AWR monitoring to only use queries of a specific user/driver **or is there another functionality I could use for conducting my performance tests**?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "system" queries? And TDE stands for?

Comment: Sure! With "system" queries I mean the queries not executed by the Java App Server which uses the DB, but by some internal jobs/optimization, e.g.:

select /*+ index(idl_ub1$ i_id......
select sql_id, sql_exec_id, db...
select a.count_snapshots, b.ho...

With Oracle TDE I mean the Transparent Data Encryption, also known as data-at-rest encryption.

Comment: Are you seeing a big regression on your cloned system? If so, how much? Is you cloned system identical to your source system? Are you able to share the AWR reports?

Comment: The cloned DB (where TDE is activated) is identical to the source system. How big the regression is, is something I want to find out. Thats why I am interested in extracting all the App Server queries because I want to replay them on both the DB's and then compare response times.

After having a confirmation that the regression is small, we would like to activate TDE in production. Unfortunately, I am not able allowed to share our AWR, but on request I can give you specific additional information.

Comment: Oh, I think I mis-understood. You are using the AWR to capture the queries you want to replay - is that right?

Comment: exactly! AWR was suggested by a colleague of mine. We are also open to other solutions besides AWR.

Comment: Maybe you should consider Real Application Testing (RAT). https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/e12253/rat_intro.htm#RATUG101

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's Automated Workload Repository (AWR) captures all database activity.  You have some flexibility in the depth of statistics it captures, but you can't filter the way you are asking for.  When you product an AWR report, you will get everything the database performed, and specifically for the SQL data, you'll get the top or highest load SQL's.  There are some additional thresholds you can set to get more SQL in the report, so instead of the top-10, you can get the top-50.  This can be set as a default or per AWR report.

More can be found here
[Oracle workload repository package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_workload_repos.htm#ARPLS093)

Comment: Thanks! This is unfortunate because the most executed, highest reponse time and highest cpu util queries are the ones I would be most interested in when doing a replay on the TDE database.

If I cannot filter AWR input, how would you extract the queries I am looking for? :-)

Comment: All the data is in the database.  Look at DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY as a start as well as the other DBA_HIST_* tables.